# How to tell if a MIDIEndpointRef is Virtual?

Tags: ios, coremidi

I'm trying to distinguish between "Virtual" and "Non-Virtual" MIDIEndpointRefs in my iOS app.

The MIDIObjectType enum seems to be the place to look, but as far as I can tell, this property is not something I can query.

Any advice?

Comment: It *is* possible to query the `MIDIObjectType` of a `MIDIObjectRef` using `MIDIObjectFindByUniqueID(_:_:_:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I was pointed to on the OMAC google group (thanks Jesse Chappell

```
static BOOL isVirtualEndpoint(MIDIEndpointRef ref)
{
    MIDIEntityRef entity = 0;

    MIDIEndpointGetEntity(ref, &entity);
    if (entity) 
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else 
    {
    return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the `MIDIEndpointRef`, try using `MIDIEndpointGetEntity` and then `MIDIEntityGetDevice` to find a device. If the entity or device are nil, then the endpoint is probably "virtual".